# How to find the row where a number starts to just increase and increase using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (70000 rows). One of the columns has many numbers. At the begining these numbers increase and decrease randomly. But there is a point where they just start to increase and increase. How can I find the row where that starts to happen?

So far I have written some code. I am using the starting value as reference (33.3). So whatever group of values just increase and increase over 33.3 is what I need. In the example dataframe, the row will be #9 (count starts from 1). Because the number before is 33.3 (row8). And the next numbers just continue increasing (never decreasing. Not even by a decimal): 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40.

```
#This line displays what rows are different from 33.3 (TRUEs and FALSEs)
df_X = df_X['TPU'] == 33.3


#With this line I check by groups of rows when does the value changed from 33.3 to something else.
df_X.iloc[80:120]
```

But I still need to iterate over groups of rows. So, it is not very effective.

SAMPLE DATAFRAME

```
df_X = {'TPU': [33.3, 32.3, 33.3, 35, 33.3, 36, 35, 33.3, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]}
```

EDIT

I CAN SEE THE POINT WHERE THE NUMBER JUST INCREASES AND INCREASE, USING A PLOT

[image]

Comment: Have many elements need to incerase in a line to decide that this is "your point"?

Comment: I thought of that too. But the thing is that the points will just increase and increase. I can see where that happens with a plot.

Comment: I added the plot.

Answer (score 3):

```
# just a flug if the next value increased
df['increasing'] = df['TPU'].shift(1)  <= df['TPU']
# by doing cumulative product, transform this flag into "all following are increasing"
df['strictly_increasing'] = df['increasing'][::-1].cumprod()[::-1]
# get the first row index
df.index[df['strictly_increasing' > 0]][0]
```

[image]

Comment: I have added an example. And I have tested your code. It gives me row #0, which is the value 33.3

Comment: This solution works only in situation when your group is at the end of data

Comment: @Aizzaac It gives you row -7, which happens to have the same value (33.3) as the first row. The last 7 values are strictly increasing, which is what I read you are looking for. Perhaps, the question also needs the expected result example

Comment: @Marat I will check again.

Comment: @CezarySzulc yes, this is how I understand the question.

Comment: @Marat on a plot we can see that values can have the same value, in this situation your solution stoped counting. Please add to sample data at the end record with value 40

Comment: @CezarySzulc that's only a matter of replacing `<` in the first line with `<=`, which I just did. I'm more concerned about occasional spikes in the data which are unclear how to deal with

Comment: @Aizzaac in the last line, I should have explicitly compare `strictly_increasing` to 0, and not to rely on implicit bool conversion. Fixed now

Comment: I get ```TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: I will post the resul that I get without using the last line

Comment: When doing it manually. I will choose row #15. It just increases over 33.3. Maybe I will post the first 20 rows of the dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df_X = pd.DataFrame({'TPU': [33.3, 32.3, 33.3, 35, 33.3, 36, 35, 33.3, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]})
df_X['shifted_TPU'] = df_X['TPU'].shift(1)
df_X['is_increasing'] = df_X['TPU'] > df_X['shifted_TPU']
df_X.head()


    TPU     shifted_TPU     is_increasing
0   33.3    NaN             False
1   32.3    33.3            False
2   33.3    32.3            True
3   35.0    33.3            True
4   33.3    35.0            False
```

Then we can check groups of increasing:

```
tmp_val = 0
list_to_df = []
for id_row, row in df_X.iterrows():
  x = row['is_increasing']*(1+tmp_val)
  tmp_val = x
  list_to_df.append(x)
df_X['sum_of_elements_incresing'] = list_to_df
```

As a result you will get:

```
df_X
    TPU     shifted_TPU     is_increasing   sum_of_elements_incresing
0   33.3    NaN             False           0
1   32.3    33.3            False           0
2   33.3    32.3            True            1
3   35.0    33.3            True            2
4   33.3    35.0            False           0
5   36.0    33.3            True            1
6   35.0    36.0            False           0
7   33.3    35.0            False           0
8   35.0    33.3            True            1
9   36.0    35.0            True            2
10  37.0    36.0            True            3
11  38.0    37.0            True            4
12  39.0    38.0            True            5
13  40.0    39.0            True            6
```

You can easy check in a column `sum_of_elements_incresing` maximum numbers of elements that are increasing.

---

EDIT

If your solution need to check that next value is not smaller (I mean increase or is on the same level) you can just edit one line in this code:

```
 df_X['is_increasing'] = df_X['TPU'] > df_X['shifted_TPU']
 # change to
 df_X['is_increasing'] = df_X['TPU'] >= df_X['shifted_TPU']
 # there was added only =
```

result

[image]

---

UPDATE #2

Regarding occasional spikes you can use some threshold. Eg. if value decrease for 0.5 will not clear your counter.

```
 df_X = pd.DataFrame({'TPU': [33.3, 32.3, 33.3, 35, 33.3, 36, 35, 33.3, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 40, 39.5, 39, 38.5, 41, 42]})
 df_X['shifted_TPU'] = df_X['TPU'].shift(1)
 df_X['is_increasing'] = (df_X['TPU'] - df_X['shifted_TPU']) >= -0.5
```

To find index when this situation is started:

```
df_X.index[df_X['sum_of_elements_incresing'] == df_X['sum_of_elements_incresing'].max()] - df_X['sum_of_elements_incresing'].max()
```

Comment: @Marat and CezarySzulc Both of your answers are ok. As my dataset is big (70000rows) it  takes time to find where the increment happens. And that is why I want the number of row. I will post both of your results.

Comment: As you see, both results are ok with small data. But with big data something happens.

Comment: @Aizzaac I added line to find this index

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand how the expected output is, if it is wrong please correct me.
I believe it is possible to do what you want compare if the current value is greater than the next with `shift(-1)`. use `cumsum` to see how many times this logic occurs (current value> next value). Use another `shift` to push everything one line forward (when the values ​​actually start to increase). 
Use `duplicated` to remove single line ranges and `drop_duplicates` to save only the first value where the numbers only increase

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TPU': [33.3, 32.3, 33.3, 35, 33.3, 36, 35, 33.3, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]})

s = (df['TPU'] > df['TPU'].shift(-1)).cumsum().shift()
idx = s[s.duplicated(keep=False)].drop_duplicates().index
df.loc[idx, 'start_to_increase'] = True

#output:
    TPU     start_to_increase
0   33.3    NaN
1   32.3    True
2   33.3    NaN
3   35.0    NaN
4   33.3    True
5   36.0    NaN
6   35.0    NaN
7   33.3    True
8   35.0    NaN
9   36.0    NaN
10  37.0    NaN
11  38.0    NaN
12  39.0    NaN
13  40.0    NaN
```